# Linking errors in FLTK 2.0 in windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt-creator, static-linking, fltk

I am using Qt Creator( without using any of Qt libraries) to test a Hello World project of FLTK2.0. But I am getting errors like:

> Errors:
>   UpBox.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
>   UpBox.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to`SetROP2@8'
>   UpBox.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to `PatBlt@24'
>   UpBox.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to`CreatePatternBrush@4'
>   UpBox.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
>   :-1: error: C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\FLTK\fltk-2.0-win-bin\lib/libfltk2.a(UpBox.o): bad reloc address 0xb in section`.text$_ZN4fltk7FlatBoxD1Ev[__ZN4fltk7FlatBoxD1Ev]'

**The main.cpp file is given below:**

```
#include <fltk/Window.h>
#include <fltk/Widget.h>
#include <fltk/run.h>

using namespace fltk;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Window *window = new Window(300, 180);
    window->begin();
    Widget *box = new Widget(20, 40, 260, 100, "Hello, World!");
    box->box(UP_BOX);
    box->labelfont(HELVETICA_BOLD_ITALIC);
    box->labelsize(36);
    box->labeltype(SHADOW_LABEL);
    window->end();
    window->show(argc, argv);
    return run();
}
```

**The hello.pro file:**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += main.cpp
CONFIG+= c++11
LIBS += -L"C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\FLTK\\fltk-2.0-win-bin\\lib" -lfltk2
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\FLTK\\fltk-2.0-win-bin\\include"
DEPENDPATH += "C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\FLTK\\fltk-2.0-win-bin\\include"
```

Why am I getting these errors?

n.b: the FLTK 2.o MinGw compiled binaries are downloaded from [FLTK Windows binaries](https://code.google.com/p/fltkwinbin/downloads/list)

Comment: Which compiler do you using?

Comment: If you do a search for e.g. `CreatePatternBrush` you should quickly find [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which tells you what *system* library you need to link with.

Comment: I am using MinGW(mingw482_32) @Sergey

Answer (score 1):

The static library FLTK is correctly linked, but it also requires to be linked to Win32 API to work on windows.

You have to link to Gdi32.dll as well.

Comment: I have added win32: LIBS += -lgdi32 -lws2_32 -lOle32 to the hello.pro file. still I am getting errors like: run.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to `IID_IUnknown',run.cxx:-1: error: undefined reference to `IID_IDropTarget'

Comment: Link to uuid.lib also?

Comment: After adding uuid.lib there are no linking errors. But when I try to run the app  it stops working. @Geoffroy

Comment: i.e. a popup box says that the application has stopped working

Comment: I run the debugger and it says that "the inferior stopped because it received a signal from operating system. Signal name: SIGSEGV, signal meaning: segmentation fault

Comment: Then it's not the same problem, post it as a different question.

Comment: I can post it after 90 min. In the meantime can you please give some insight what to do? @Geoffroy

Comment: You're accessing a memory segment which you should not, hence the segv. I don't know how fltk works so I can't help you more sorry

Comment: @user1659459 as this seems to solve your question, accept the answer