# segmentation fault while running FLTK based application

Tags: windows, qt-creator, mingw32, fltk

I am trying to run an application based on FLTK2.0. The application builds successfully without any error message but when I try to run it only a command line window appears. I ran it in debugger and a popup box appears which says that

> "the inferior stopped because it received a signal from operating system. Signal name: SIGSEGV, signal meaning: segmentation fault

Please refer to this  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680191/linking-errors-in-fltk-2-0-in-windows) for reference

Comment: I've never used mingw with FLTK2 on a windows platform.  It works fine if you run it with visual studio express.  Just use the solution in the IDE directory and you'll be up in 15 minutes.

Comment: SIGSEGV may happen for various reasons. It is most likely not caused by FLTK (or you encountered a FLTK bug - if so, please report it)... Dereferencing a null pointer will cause SIGSEGV and it is the most common C++ error...

Comment: Second typical SIGSEGV problem: `char *s = "hello world"; *s = 'H';`

Comment: If it is a short program, can you post it?

Comment: How is that question relevant to what you are asking??